# catalog_product_view.xml - move block to sidebar problem

Tags: magento2, xml

I want to move to the sidebar, only on the product view.

To achieve this I've created `catalog_product_view.xml` in `Vendor/Name/Magento_Theme/layout/`.

I've added the following line:

```
<move element="product.info.main" destination="sidebar.additional"/>
```

But now the product.info.main-block jumps BELOW the footer, which obviously isn't what I wanted to achieve.

My question now is: how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you 1column page layout or 2 columns?

Comment: How can I check the template used for product pages? by default it should be page-2column-right, or am I wrong?

Comment: Have you working for detail page or category listing page?

Comment: catalog_product_view.xml targets the product detail page.

Comment: sidebar.additional is not called inside product view page

Comment: Just found out that the 1column tmeplate is loaded. How can I switch to 2column-right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't answer with comment because i lack reputation points, but to change to 2 columns you need to change this line of your xml-layout file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```